# differences when compiling a project using flex builder and flex sdk

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, sdk, comparison, flexbuilder

The following code compiles fine in flex builder 3, but throws an error when compiled using the command line and flex sdk 3.3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ww:TestApplication
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:ww="*"
    layout="absolute"
    backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    >
    <mx:Label x="10" y="10" text="simple test"/>
</ww:TestApplication>
```

The error message is: Unable to locate specified base class 'TestApplication' for component class 'TestApplication'.

The problem only happens when I use the default package for my custom classes. If instead I use

```
xmlns:ww="somepackage.*"
```

and change my matching AS class accordingly, then it compiles fine using the sdk. Am I missing an argument when compiling or something? Are there differences when compiling a project using flex builder and flex sdk? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths have to be explicitly defined using mxmlc or compc. Here is an explanation of the flags:

> source-path is used to define the path to the source if it is not in the default:

```
mxmlc -source-path path1 path2 path3 c:/myFiles/app.mxml
```

> library-path is used to define the path to libraries:

```
mxmlc -library-path [AIR SDK]/frameworks/libs/air/airframework.swc, ^ [AIR SDK]/frameworks/libs/air/airframework.swc, ^ -library-path [Flex SDK]/frameworks/libs/framework.swc ^ -- myApp.mxml
```

> file-specs is used to define the mxml file:

```
mxmlc --strict=true --file-specs MyFirst.mxml
```

> runtime-shared-libraries is used to define the RSL path:

```
mxmlc -external-library-path+=../lib/myLib.swc -runtime-shared-libraries=myrsl.swf -- myApp.mxml
```

**References**

- [Flex command line flags](http://www.docsultant.com/site2/articles/flex_cmd.html)
- [Flex 3 Compiler Design](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Flex%203%20Compiler%20Design/)
- [Technical Guide: Upgrading Flex 3 applications to Flex 4 SDK (pdf)](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flex/pdfs/upgrading-flex3-to-flex4-techguide.pdf)
- [Adobe AIR * ActionScript compilers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2012b5a4128cca83a39-8000.html)
- [Flex Quick Start - Coding with MXML and ActionScript | Adobe Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstarts/coding_mxml_as.html)
- [Adobe Flex 4.6 - Invoking the command-line compilers with Java](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a88.html)
- [Adobe Flex 4.6 - About the application compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)
- [Adobe Flex 4.6 - Compiling components with Flex SDK](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68391-7ffa.html)
- [Adobe Flex 4.6 - Compiling an application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf614b9-7ff3.html)
- [Using Adobe Flex 4 Compiler API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/CompilerAPI/flex_4.0_compilerapi.pdf)